# write textarea content from jsp page to text file

Tags: java, jsp, writetofile

I have jsp page that has a textarea and submit button.

form.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="submitForm">
            <label for="commentTxt">Comments: </label><br />
            <textarea rows="20" cols="100" id="commentTxt" name="commentTxt" 
                placeholder="Enter your comments."></textarea><br />

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

        </form>
```

I want to write the comments to text file, so in the servlet I have this code that call a java method to write to a txt file.

submitForm.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //doGet(request, response);
    // get user comments
    String comments = request.getParameter("commentTxt");
    FilesRW.writeStrTxt(comments);

}
```

FilesRW.java

```
    public static void writeStrTxt( String str){
     FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    try{
        FileWriter wr = new FileWriter( new File("userComments.txt"));
        System.out.println(str);// this line print user comments in console
        wr.write(str);
        wr.close();
    }catch (IOException exe) {
         exe.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I don't know what is the problem because user comments is sent to the fileRW class and i can print it to the console and see the user comments. However, when i open the file, is empty.  Also, when I try to use the writeStrTxt(String) method in the main of the same class (FilesRW.java) it works and it writes a text to the file.

I need to call this method in servlet class (submitForm.java), but it does not write the text to the file. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: the path is the same folder of the class so the path is fine, but still the file empty

Comment: You are using relative path. It is relative to where the Java process was started, in this case, Tomcat/bin. Please look for the file there. As @Aleksey Bykov   suggested, you could use an absolute path.  You could the getRealPath method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call wr.flush() before closing.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#flush()

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 System.out.println(str);
```

to

```
 System.out.println("* "+str);
```

and verify if there is no second empty request.

Comment: the problem is in writing to file, not to console.

Comment: Yes but you might write twice to file. First the comments and then overwrite it with empty text. But this is just a hint.